# Why there are no "unsigned wchar_t" and "signed wchar_t" types?

Tags: c, standards, wchar-t, widechar, c-standard-library

The signedness of char is not standardized. Hence there are `signed char` and `unsigned char` types. Therefore functions which work with single character must use the argument type which can hold both signed char and unsigned char (this
type was chosen to be `int`), because if the argument type was `char`, we would
get type conversion warnings from the compiler (if -Wconversion is used) in code like this:

```
char c = 'ÿ';
if (islower((unsigned char) c)) ...

warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘unsigned char’ may change the sign of the result
```

(*here we consider what would happen if the argument type of islower() was char*)

And the thing which makes it work without explicit typecasting is automatic promotion
from `char` to `int`.

Further, the ISO C90 standard, where `wchar_t` was introduced, does not say anything
specific about the representation of `wchar_t`.

Some quotations from glibc reference:

> it would be legitimate to define `wchar_t` as `char`

> if `wchar_t` is defined as `char` the type `wint_t` must be defined as `int` due to the parameter promotion.

So, `wchar_t` can perfectly well be defined as `char`, which means that similar rules
for wide character types must apply, i.e., there may be implementations where
`wchar_t` is positive, and there may be implementations where `wchar_t` is negative.
From this it follows that there must exist `unsigned wchar_t` and `signed wchar_t` types (for the same reason as there are `unsigned char` and `signed char` types).

Private communication reveals that an implementation is allowed to support wide
characters with >=0 value only (independently of signedness of `wchar_t`). Anybody knows what this means? Does thin mean that when `wchar_t` is 16-bit
type (for example), we can only use 15 bits to store the value of wide character?
In other words, is it true that a sign-extended `wchar_t` is a valid value?
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755519/).

Also, private communication reveals that the standard requires that any valid value of `wchar_t` must
representable by `wint_t`. Is it true?

Consider this example:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main (void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "fr_FR.ISO-8859-1");

  /* 11111111 */
  char c = 'ÿ';

  if (islower(c)) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

To make it portable, we need the cast to '(unsigned char)'.
This is necessary because `char` may be the equivalent `signed char`,
in which case a byte where the top bit is set would be sign
extended when converting to `int`, yielding a value that is outside
the range of `unsigned char`.

Now, why is this scenario different from the following example for
wide characters?

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
  wchar_t wc = L'ÿ';

  if (iswlower(wc)) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

We need to use `iswlower((unsigned wchar_t)wc)` here, but
there is no `unsigned wchar_t` type.

Why there are no `unsigned wchar_t` and `signed wchar_t` types?

**UPDATE**

Are the standards saying that casting to `unsigned int` and to `int` in the following two programs is guaranteed to be correct?
(I just replaced `wint_t` and `wchar_t` to their actual meaning in glibc)

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
  unsigned int wc;
  wc = getwchar();
  putwchar((int) wc);
}
```

--

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
  int wc;
  wc = L'ÿ';
  if (iswlower((unsigned int) wc)) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is char neither signed or unsigned, but wchar\_t is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856481/why-is-char-neither-signed-or-unsigned-but-wchar-t-is)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR:

> Why there are no unsigned wchar_t and signed wchar_t types?

Because C's wide-character handling facilities were defined such that they are not needed.

---

In more detail,

> The signedness of char is not standardized.

To be precise, "The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char." (C2011, 6.2.5/15)

> Hence there are `signed char` and `unsigned char` types.

"Hence" implies causation, which would be hard to argue clearly, but certainly `signed char` and `unsigned char` are more appropriate when you want to handle numbers, as opposed to characters.

> Therefore functions which work with single character must use the argument type which can hold both signed char and unsigned char

No, not at all.  Standard library functions that work with individual characters could easily be defined in terms of type `char`, regardless of whether that type is signed, because the library implementation *does* know its signedness.  If that were a problem then it would apply equally to the string functions, too -- `char` would be useless.

Your example of `getchar()` is non-apposite.  It returns `int` rather than a character type because it needs to be able to return an error indicator that does not correspond to any character.  Moreover, the code you present does not correspond to the accompanying warning message: it contains a conversion from `int` to `unsigned char`, but no conversion from `char` to `unsigned char`.

Some other character-handling functions accept `int` parameters or return values of type `int` both for compatibility with `getchar()` and other stdio functions, and for historic reasons.  In days of yore, you couldn't actually pass a `char` at all -- it would always be promoted to `int`, and that is what the functions would (and must) accept.  One cannot later change the argument type, evolution of the language notwithstanding.

> Further, the ISO C90 standard, where `wchar_t` was introduced, does not say anything specific about the representation of `wchar_t`.

C90 isn't really relevant any longer, but no doubt it says something very similar to C2011 (7.19/2), which describes `wchar_t` as

> an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales [...].

Your quotations from the glibc reference are non-authoritative, except possibly for glibc only.  They appear in any case to be commentary, not specification, and its unclear why you raise them.  Certainly, though, at least the first is correct.  Referring to the standard, if all the members of the largest extended character set specified among the locales supported by a given implementation could fit in a `char` then that implementation could define `wchar_t` as `char`.  Such implementations used to be much more common than they are today.

You ask several questions:

> Private communication reveals that an implementation is allowed to support wide characters with >=0 value only (independently of signedness of `wchar_t`). Anybody knows what this means?

I think it means that whoever communicated that to you doesn't know what they are talking about, or perhaps that what they are talking about is something different than the requirements placed by the C standard.  You will find that *in practice*, character sets are defined with only non-negative character codes, but that is not a constraint placed by the C standard.

> Does thin mean that when `wchar_t` is 16-bit type (for example), we can only use 15 bits to store the value of wide character?

The C standard does not say or imply that.  You can store the value of any supported character in a `wchar_t`.  In particular, if an implementation supports a character set containing character codes exceeding 32767, then you can store those in a `wchar_t`.

> In other words, is it true that a sign-extended wchar_t is a valid value?

The C standard does not say or imply that.  It does not even say whether `wchar_t` is a signed type (if not, then sign extension is meaningless for it).  If it is a signed type, then there is no guarantee about whether sign-extending a value representing a character in some supported character set (which value could, in principle, be negative) will produce a value that also represents a character in that character set, or in any other supported character set.  The same is true of adding 1 to a `wchar_t` value.

> Also, private communication reveals that the standard requires that any valid value of `wchar_t` must representable by `wint_t`. Is it true?

It depends what you mean by "valid".  The standard says that `wint_t`

> is an integer type unchanged by default argument promotions that can hold any value corresponding to members of the extended character set, as well as at least one value that does not correspond to any member of the extended character set.

(C2011, 7.29.1/2)

`wchar_t` must be able to hold any value corresponding to a member of the extended character set, in any supported locale.  `wint_t` must be able to hold all of those values, too.  It may be, however, that `wchar_t` is capable of representing values that do not correspond to any character in any supported character set.  Such values are valid in the sense that the type can represent them.  `wint_t` is not required to be able to represent such values.

For example, if the largest extended character set of any supported locale uses character codes up to but not exceeding 32767, then an implementation would be free to implement `wchar_t` as an unsigned 16-bit integer, and `wint_t` as a signed 16-bit integer.  The values representable by `wchar_t` that do not correspond to extended characters are then not representable by `wint_t` (but `wint_t` still has many candidates for its required value that does not correspond to any character).

With respect to the character and wide-character classification functions, the only answer is that the differences simply arise from different specifications.  The `char` classification functions are defined to work with the same values that `getchar()` is defined to return -- either -1 or a character value converted, if necessary, to `unsigned char`.  The wide character classification functions, on the other hand, accept arguments of type `wint_t`, which can represent the values of all wide-character unchanged, therefore there is no need for a conversion.

You claim in this regard that

> We need to use `iswlower((unsigned wchar_t)wc)` here, but there is no `unsigned wchar_t` type.

No and maybe.  You do not need to convert the `wchar_t` argument to `iswlower()` to any other type, and in particular, you do not need to convert it to an explicitly unsigned type.  The wide character classification functions are not analogous to the regular character classification functions in this respect, having been designed with the benefit of hindsight.  As for `unsigned wchar_t`, C does not require such a type to exist, so portable code should not use it, but it may exist in some implementations.

---

### Regarding the update appended to the question:

> Are the standards saying that casting to unsigned int and to int in the following two programs is guaranteed to be correct? (I just replaced wint_t and wchar_t to their actual meaning in glibc)

The standard says nothing of the sort about conforming implementations in general.  I'll suppose, however, that you mean to ask specifically about conforming implementations for which `wchar_t` is `int` and `wint_t` is `unsigned int`.

On such an implementation, your first program is flawed because it does not account for the possibility that `getwchar()` returns `WEOF`.  Converting `WEOF` to type `wchar_t`, if doing so does not cause a signal to be raised, is not guaranteed to produce a value that corresponds to any wide character. Passing the result of such a conversion to `putwchar()` therefore does not exhibit defined behavior.  Moreover, if `WEOF` is defined with the same value as `UINT_MAX` (which is not representable by `int`) then the conversion of that value to `int` has implementation-defined behavior independently of the `putwchar()` call.

On the other hand, I think the key point you are struggling with is that if the value returned by `getwchar()` in the first program is not `WEOF`, then it is guaranteed to be one that is unchanged by conversion to `wchar_t`.  Your first program will perform as appears to be intended in that case, but the cast to `int` (or `wchar_t`) is unnecessary.

Similarly, the second program is correct provided that the wide-character literal corresponds to a character in the applicable extended character set, but the cast is unnecessary and changes nothing.  The `wchar_t` value of such a literal is guaranteed to be representable by type `wint_t`, so the cast changes the type of its operand, but not the value.  (But if the literal does not correspond to a character in the extended character set then the behavior is implementation-defined.)

On the third hand, if your objective is to write strictly-conforming code then the right thing to do, and indeed the intended usage mode of these particular wide-character functions, would be this:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
  wint_t wc = getwchar();
  if (wc != WEOF) {
    // No cast is necessary or desirable
    putwchar(wc);
  }
}
```

and this:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");
  wchar_t wc = L'ÿ';
  // No cast is necessary or desirable
  if (iswlower(wc)) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: "Standard library functions that work with individual characters could easily be defined in terms of type char" - this would make the code not portable.

Comment: "Your example of getchar() is non-apposite" - thanks, I fixed that.

Comment: "One cannot later change the argument type" - the argument type `int` is justified - it need not be changed (see first example)

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, I repeat: standard library functions, or really any library functions, can be defined to accept parameters of type `char` without affecting portability.  One cannot *re*define *existing* library functions to take arguments of different types, and type `char` might not be appropriate for the specific purposes of a given function, but the fact that the signedness of `char` is implementation-defined does not inherently impact the portability of such functions.

Comment: To make the code portable, we have to use (unsigned char) cast. But on a platform where char is signed by default this will produce warnings (see first example). How to make a function accept `char` and get rid of the conversion warnings? Maybe this should be asked as a separate question?

Comment: See **UPDATE** in OP.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, if you want to pass a `char` value to one of the character classification functions, you must cast it to `unsigned char` because only that guarantees to produce the `int` value that you need to provide to those functions.  This is a consequence of the specifications of *those particular functions* in terms of `unsigned char` values, not a general consequence of the signedness of `char` being implementation-defined.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, I have now added a response to your update.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. One nit: "`wint_t` is not required to be able to represent such values" -- I think `wint_t` is actually required to be able to represent at least one of those values, which serves as the error sentinel value you refer to earlier in your answer.

Comment: @HaldeanBrown, `win_t` is required to be able to represent at least one value that does not correspond to any character of any extended character set of any supported locale, but that value is not required to be one of those that `wchar_t` can represent.  For example, `wchar_t` might be a 22-bit unsigned integer type capable of representing every Unicode code point plus some values that are greater than any Unicode code point, with `wint_t` being a 22-bit signed integer able to represent every Unicode code point plus some negative values.

Comment: @HaldeanBrown, but I have added a clarification on this point to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Why in char API we cast to (unsigned char) when we call, say islower(), but in wchar_t API we cast to (wint_t) (explicitly or implicitly). The logic says that we must cast to (unsigned wchar_t). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061489/